# Edit row in PrimeVue dataTable strips image tag

Tags: vue.js, datatables, primevue

I am trying to use primevue datatables to accomplish certain cell editing. you can only edit 3 columns of the table. I am using the :rowEditor="true" on the datatable directive to accomplish being able to edit multiple columns. The issue is, when I hit the edit button, my image tag gets stripped and I'm left with a URL. I have tried putting many tags on it like :editable="false" but nothing is working. anyone know how to disable this feature on a certain column?

[primeVue edit documentation](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/datatable/edit)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I have found a workaround but I am still open to implementing a better solution.

```js
<Column field="image_url" header="Image" :editable="false">
    <template #body="{data}">
        <img :src="data.image_url" :alt="data.image_url" class="product-image"/>
    </template>
    <template #editor="slotProps">
        <div v-html="renderHtml(slotProps)"></div>
    </template>
</Column>
```

```js
renderHtml(data) {
    let src = data.data.image_url,
    alt = data.data.image_url;

    return '<img src="' + src + '" alt="' + alt +'" class="product-image" />';
}
```